# Find out how deep a call stack went in Clojure (or java)

Tags: recursion, clojure, stack-overflow

Clojure is my first foray into the world of lisp. I decided to try a simple recursive function that raises a number to an integer power. Simple enough.

```
(defmulti pow #(compare %2 0))
(defmethod pow 0 [a n] 1)
(defmethod pow 1 [a n] (* a (pow a (dec n))))
(defmethod pow -1 [a n] (/ 1 (pow a (* -1 n))))
```

It works fine if you only pass integer powers. But I get stack overflows (predictably) when I use it to raise to a large enough power.

The question is, how can I find out exactly how deep the function IS recursing before it dies? One way to get a ballpark on how deep I *can* recurse is by doing something like:

```
(defn max-depth [n] 
    (try
        (max-depth (inc n))
    (catch StackOverflowError err (do
        (printf "%s at %d\n" err n)
        n)
)))
```

(Clojure is my first foray in to lisp so I don't really know how to make the code look readable.) This code just recurses infinitely until it overflows the stack, then returns the number of recursions that took place before it blew up. This only gives me a ballpark figure of how deep I'm allowed to go... There are a lot of problems with this approach.

Another thing I can do is catch the exception and try to unwind the stack myself... But I don't really see a way to get the information that I want from the exception. Looking at the javadoc for StackOverflowError at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html I see a few methods that look promising, but nothing panned out as far as I could see.

I tried running (count (.getStackTrace error)) where error is the stackoverflow that I caught, but the result was just 1024 since "under some circumstances, stack frames may be ommited". So that didn't work.

The only other thing I could think of would be to run pow over succesively larger exponents, but again that doesn't really tell me how deeply the call stack got, it only tells me how large of an exponent I can raise to (since the function calls other functions, the two answers are not the same).

I don't know of any way to do it in java either, but if there is one, then that answer would also probably be helpful.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
--Scott

Answer (score 2):

I'd have thought that `(.getStackTrace error)` is your best bet - why do you think it isn't working?

A recursion depth of 1024 before blowing the stack for a simple function sounds about what I would expect.

Remember that single Clojure functions often get transformed into several JVM method calls, so the actual JVM stack depth could be considerable deeper than your recursion valiable `n`. If you want to convert from the stack trace back to `n`, you will probably need to count the number of times a recursive call to the multimethod appears in the stack trace.

Comment: I was suspicious since 1024 is such a perfect, round number in computing. I just assumed they truncated it to 2^10 slots (since they're allowed to do that). Also, looking at the stack frames line by line, i see nothing at all but a bunch of alternating "clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)" and "user$eval157$fn__158.invoke(powtest:5)" which wouldn't be the case if it was a FULL stack trace -- it would have the method that called it among other things.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the max recursion depth that I get from max-depth is usually in the high 9,900's, close to but not exactly at 10,000, about nine to ten times greater than the stack trace would indicate.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not actually going to answer your question - because I think trying to debug call stack depth is the wrong way to solve this problem. Instead I'm going to suggest a more effective approach to recursion in Clojure, which doesn't risk blowing the call stack.

The important concept is 'tail-call elimination' - which basically means that if function F is a recursive function, and the last thing it does is call itself, you can optimize that. For the nth recursive call of F, the last thing it does is call the n+1th recursive call of F and return that value to the n-1th call of F - so you can overwrite all the stack data relating to the nth call of F, and have the n+1th call return its value directly to the n-1st call. So this basically means you only need one place on the stack instead of hundreds or thousands.

The JVM doesn't natively support this optimization for function calls - otherwise your example would probably work. Instead, Clojure provides the recur operator, which reuses the current loop or function call rather than increasing the stack. I'd use this to rewrite your function like this (I've left out your support for negative exponents for simplicity's sake):

```
user=> (defn pow
  #_=>   ([base exp] (pow base exp base)) ; default the accumulator argument to the base of the power
  #_=>   ([base exp acc] (if (= exp 1)
  #_=>                         acc ; base case - return the accumulated power
  #_=>                         (recur base (dec exp) (* base acc))))) ; recur, decrementing the power
#'user/pow
user=> 

user=> (pow 1 10000000) ; stack not blown
1
user=> (pow 2 10)
1024
```

See also: http://clojure.org/functional_programming#Functional%20Programming--Recursive%20Looping and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Of course, this implementation of pow is just a recursion example - anyone reading this should use Math/pow instead for real work.

```
user=> (time (Math/pow 1 10000000))
"Elapsed time: 0.166723 msecs"
1.0
user=> (time (pow 1 10000000))
"Elapsed time: 2991.321703 msecs"
1
user=> (time (pow 2 1000))

ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
user=> (time (Math/pow 2 1000))
"Elapsed time: 0.069109 msecs"
1.0715086071862673E301
```